# react-navigation on back-pressed stacknavigator inside tabnavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am using `createBottomTabNavigator()` as the main navigator, and each tab has a `StackNavigator`. But when the back button is pressed on a screen inside the stack (ex. `ProbableCases` screen), it navigates me to exit the app instead of back to the previous screen.

Below is my navigator structure,

```
const MapTab = createStackNavigator({
  MapContainer: {
    screen: MapContainer
  },
  ProbableCases: {
    screen: ProbableCases
  },
});

const LoggedInTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Map: {
    screen: MapTab,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Map',
      tabBarIcon: CustomTabBarIcon('ios-map', 22),
    },
  },
  ...
}, {
  backBehavior: 'none',
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
});
```

Many suggests to use `backBehavior: 'none'` config, but it still doesn't work.

```
"react-native": "0.60.5"
"react-navigation": "^4.0.2"
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.5.5"
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.5"
```

Is there a bug with v4?

Comment: can you share an working example in an expo snack so that we can check and help?

Comment: What do you mean by exiting the app? The app crashes?

Comment: Its not, I mean it just exit safely as there was no more screen behind the screen where I pressed the back button on.